# Django how to test whether password validators are being used

Tags: python, django, authentication

My Django settings file contains the following password validators:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

I am using django allauth and django restauth to set up authentication endpoints.

If I post to the registration endpoint with a password that is too short, too common, or only numeric, I receive and appropriate error message. Here's an example with all three:

```
{
    "email": "toasterffs@gmail.com",
    "password1": "1223",
    "password2": "1223"
}

{
    "password1": [
        "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.",
        "This password is too common.",
        "This password is entirely numeric."
    ],
}
```

When I post to the registration endpoint with a password that is the same as the email address, I receive no error.

I need to debug this but where to even start?

I there somewhere I can inspect which validators are actually called?

Can I monkey patch the validator and put some logging in to see where things are going wrong? Is there a signal? some other hook?
Thanks

UPDATE:
NixeTrixe suggests that email is not validated against.

The docs seem to say otherwise?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/

("The user_attributes parameter should be an iterable of names of user attributes to compare to. If this argument is not provided, the default is used: 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'. Attributes that don’t exist are ignored.")

I tried changing my settings as follows:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'user_attributes': ['email']
            }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would debug the Validators, but the "UserAttributeSimilarityValidator" does not run checks on the django.user "email" attribute, but rather the "username" attribute, so I think that is the root of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and welcome to SO. Please see the update on my question. Could you share where you saw that email is not checked against? I cannot verify this.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, unable to verify as I was only speaking from past experience, I agree that the docs suggest the 'email' attribute should be verified against. 

Hard to reproduce the bug, it works on my Django version (3.1.8), would recommend upgrading to the latest stable version if you haven't already. Maybe something with the libraries you mentioned is the source of the bug?

Comment: If you attempt to create a user on the admin page and you're still able to reproduce the bug I suggest posting a bug to the Django team